# Copy id from a table to another

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that sets the details of a product, I enter the details as parameters as for now, the details are entered to two different tables the Products table and the Book table, I was able to set the details in place, but I also want to get the ProductID from the Product table to the Book table where the column is also called ProductId.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductDetails] 

@Name nvarchar(50),
@Deascription nvarchar(255),
@Image image,
@Price nvarchar(50),
@Val1 nvarchar(50),
@Val2 nvarchar(50),
@Val3 nvarchar(50)

AS
     INSERT INTO Products
     VALUES (@Name, @Deascription, @Image, @Price);
                 
     INSERT INTO Book(ISBN, Amount, Auther)
     VALUES (@Val1,@Val2,@Val3);

     INSERT INTO Book(ProductID)  //F_K referencing Products.ProductID
     SELECT ProductID FROM Products
     WHERE Products.ProductName=@Name AND Products.Deascription=@Deascription;
```

This procedure is executed by this.

```
exec ProductDetails book23, 'id should be=23', NULL, 23, 233, 23, bookers;
```

Now the problem is that the id shifts 1 row down when its inserted into the second table, check Pics.

[image: Products Table]

[image: it shifts down in 2nd table!]

Comment: You're doing 2 separate `INSERT` statements into `Book`; of course you'll get 2 rows. You need to do `INSERT` all the values in one go.

Comment: *Side note, they're spelt Amount, Author and Description. :)*

Comment: Don't Embarrass me in front of everyone lol, thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not shifting. You are doing two `INSERT` statements with the second one JUST inserting the `ProductID`.

If you want to insert everything into the same row, do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Book
(
    ISBN, 
    Amount, 
    Author,
    ProductID
)
SELECT
    @Val1,
    @Val2,
    @Val3,
    p.ProductID
FROM Products as p
 WHERE p.ProductName=@Name 
 AND p.Description=@Description;
```

NOTE: This is with the corrected spelling mistakes for Description, author and Amount